# Почему при разных видах запроса к БД ModX возникает разница времени формирования страниц?

Tags: mysql, modx

Вывожу цифры в ModX Revo (вставлено в низ шаблона):

```
MySQL: [^qt^], [^q^] request(s), PHP: [^p^], total: [^t^], document from [^s^]
```

Код сниппета - **1 вариант** (вывод 32 строк по 5 ячеек из БД):

```
$query = $modx->query($sql); while ($i= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {блабла}
```

Смотрю цифры:

> MySQL: 0.4114 s, 32 request(s), PHP: 0.1472 s, total: 0.5586 s, document from database
>
> MySQL: 0.3293 s, 3 request(s), PHP: 0.0904 s, total: 0.4197 s, document from cache

Код сниппета - **2 вариант** :

```
$query = $modx->prepare($sql); $query->execute(); while ($i= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {блабла}
```

Смотрю цифры:

> MySQL: 0.0098 s, 31 request(s), PHP: 0.5625 s, total: 0.5722 s,
>   document from database
>   MySQL: 0.0005 s, 2 request(s), PHP: 0.4296 s,
>   total: 0.4301 s, document from cache

Как так? Общее время формирования страницы по сути одно и тоже, но вариации в составляющих.. Какой же способ выбрать?

**UPD.**
Версия ModX Revo.
Вывод из кастомной таблицы.
Запрос: `SELECT text, link FROM custom_table WHERE order_id>0`
Зачем? На сайте большая посещаемость, для каждого посетителя должен будет осуществляться данный запрос, кеш не возможен, так как данные в таблице обновляются каждые 5-10 минут. Делать кеш на 10 минут? Возможно))) То есть при большой нагрузке что-то будет более тонким или PHP Или MySQL.

Comment: Во втором ты используешь какой-то хитрый вывод через $modx->getChunk?

Comment: в смысле? сниппет вставлен в шаблон, код сниппета наверху приведен... в цикле echo $i['fields_name']

Comment: Сниппет вызывается напрямую в шаблоне, чанки вообще никоим образом не участвуют

Comment: Ты не указал никакой дополнительной информации - ни что за версия модикс, ни зачем тебе это надо. Что это за таблицы, какие данные...

Comment: обновил вопрос...

Comment: Данные из таблицы должны быть привязаны к пользователю или одни для всех пользователей на эти 5-10 минут?

Comment: данные одни и те же для всех

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по общему таймингу страницы, разное время на выполнение запроса - это просто какой-то дефект измерения, а не фактическая разница. Код, состоящий из prepare и execute делает ровно то же самое, что и простой вызов query (если, конечно подготовленное выражение не используется повторно, чего нет в этом примере).